# php preg_match not working as in other web applications

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Trying to parse the value of the following element:

> input type="hidden" name="csrf_token"
>   value="VUNht8fnmxmJXJIMassWW8SAwWKNJ3SC8POA4FtSqEKhG1rcoB3ZNqcPqa615tPsF_hzW0l4zDjSEHJYMz9Ogw==">

Area around the element looks like this:

```
          <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="invite_code" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="invite" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="country" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="325fTt31vp42rbt90gNqBT923_Z04snI5tmhCOAhSzpmL2mr3NBAho1zp6bEirZrLdQna5Ocm6_iC3OYdbBqLg==">

          <div>
```

With the following code line:

```
preg_match("/csrf_token. value=.(.+==).>/", $result, $output_array);
```

$output_array is left empty, where as in http://www.phpliveregex.com/ the regex is correct.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: `"/csrf_token. value=.(.+?==).>/s"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew does not seem to work, also the /s specifies that the dot matches a new line and i don't want that.

Comment: Works here, https://eval.in/590926. Maybe your `$result` isn't what you expected.. Also using a parser you could just pull the attribute `value`'s value.

Comment: @chris85, sounds like the better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Regex Way

Replace the literal space with `\s+`:

```
preg_match("/csrf_token.\s+value=.(.+==).>/", $result, $output_array);
```

Also, you probably want to improve a couple of other things here. Some suggestions:

- Instead of `.` to match the `"`, use `['\"]?` (less general, avoids matching on something random like `csrf_token2`).
- Instead of `.+==`, use `[^='"]+=*` (same result, but much better performance, and matches tokens that end in 1 or zero `=`s).

With these suggestions, your code would be:

```
preg_match("/csrf_token['\"]?\s+value=['\"]?([^='\"]+=*)['\"]?>/", $result, $output_array);
```

Here's a [**working demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lJ9xO2/1).

## The Better Way

Don't parse HTML with regex, at all. Just use a parser.

Comment: Does not seem to work either, gonna go with what @chris85 said about using a parser.

Answer (score 5):

Just to put my two cents in, a way with an xpath query using `DOMDocument`:

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOF
          <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="invite_code" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="invite" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="country" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="325fTt31vp42rbt90gNqBT923_Z04snI5tmhCOAhSzpmL2mr3NBAho1zp6bEirZrLdQna5Ocm6_iC3OYdbBqLg==">
          <div>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$inputs = $xpath->query("//input[@name='csrf_token']/@value");
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    echo $input->nodeValue;
    # 325fTt31vp42rbt90gNqBT923_Z04snI5tmhCOAhSzpmL2mr3NBAho1zp6bEirZrLdQna5Ocm6_iC3OYdbBqLg==
}

// alternatively, if you're sure there's ALWAYS only ONE element, pick the first one
echo $xpath->query('//input[@name="csrf_token"]/@value')->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/9TTmrz).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a parser version:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="VUNht8fnmxmJXJIMassWW8SAwWKNJ3SC8POA4FtSqEKhG1rcoB3ZNqcPqa615tPsF_hzW0l4zDjSEHJYMz9Ogw==">');
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('input') as $input) {
    if ($input->getAttribute('name') == 'csrf_token') {
        echo $input->getAttribute('value');
    }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/590936

Answer (score 2):

Use a DOM parser to fetch all the values you need with `'//input[@name="csrf_token"]'` XPath (namely, get all `input` tags that contain a `name` attribute with the `csrf_token` value).

See an [example](https://ideone.com/DcPM2c):

```
$html = <<<DATA
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="invite_code" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="invite" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="325fTt31vp42rbt90gNqBT923_Z04snI5tmhCOAhSzpmL2mr3NBAho1zp6bEirZrLdQna5Ocm6_iC3OYdbBqLg==">
</div>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$inputs = $xpath->query('//input[@name="csrf_token"]');
$res = array();
foreach($inputs as $input) { 
   array_push($res, $input->getAttribute("value"));
}
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 325fTt31vp42rbt90gNqBT923_Z04snI5tmhCOAhSzpmL2mr3NBAho1zp6bEirZrLdQna5Ocm6_iC3OYdbBqLg==
)
```

Comment: You could access it directly: `echo $xpath->query('//input[@name="csrf_token"]/@value')->item(0)->nodeValue;` if there's always only **one** element.

Comment: What if there are more? I just showed a way to get all of those values. Certainly, we do not know the actual HTML, and the requirements are not clear.

Comment: You know the answer, then looping over the result as you're already doing is the way to go :)

Comment: The second parameter of the DOMDocument constructor is only useful when you want to create a new document from scratch, overwise, the encoding is always overwritten either with the one found in the document (a meta tag, the byte order mark, the xml declaration) or with the default one (utf-8 most of the time). Whatever the case, when you specify the encoding in the constructor, and you use after `DOMDocument::load*`, the encoding is systematically overwritten. *(same thing for the first parameter, if you specify an xml version and use after `DOMDocument::loadHTML`)*